# plotkml raster displays a red X instead of the image

Tags: r, kml, raster

Raster image can be downloaded here:

https://github.com/Alexvonrass/BS_Selection_tool/blob/master/data/msc_raster.RDS

I run this code:

```
r <- readRDS("msc_raster.RDS")
kml(r, colour = r@data@values, file='ms.kml')
```

Then i get these warnings (not sure if they are related to the problem or not)

```
KML file opened for writing...
Writing to KML...
Closing  ms.kml
Warning messages:
1: In paths(show.paths = TRUE) :
  Could not locate GDAL! Install program and add it to the Windows registry. See http://www.gdal.org/ for more info.
2: In paths(show.paths = TRUE) :
  Could not locate SAGA GIS! Install program and add it to the Windows registry. See http://www.saga-gis.org/en/ for more info.
```

I get a kml file with the correct legend, correct position and size of the raster image, but instead of the actual image there's a red X:

[http://imgur.com/a/Xzado](https://imgur.com/a/Xzado)

It does write the desired image into the .png, but doesn't put it into the .kml
I'm thinking it has something to do with the filename of .png image that r writes, but i can't get it working at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plotKML` seems to mess up the referencing of the png to display. It can't find it, hence the red X.

A simple workaround is to just add the parameter `raster_name` to your function call:

`kml(r,raster_name = 'layer.png', colour = r@data@values, file='ms.kml')`